# Automatic logon on machine disabled after accessing the domain

Tags: login, domain

Hi I have a machine that runs with a Windows 7 IPC.

Before it was automatically logging in without a password.
User machine.
Password none.

Now I have joined it to our domain. So I have to login at bootup. I have the option of logging in locally but the empty password string is not availible any more. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Quick guess; Domain policy disables automatic logon.

Comment: Hi Michael you are right. I had changed the name of the computer. And the domin automatically turned the auto start off.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because the automatic boot up sequence had the old name of the pc. I changed the name in the regedit file and it could boot up again